# How do I validate a zipcode in a textbox and have the corresponding state/city output to their respective labels

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to write a pretty straight forward program that pulls data from my SQL Server database. And outputs the correct state and city in they're respective labels from a valid zip code entered in a textbox.

Here's some code I was messing around with. It obviously doesn't work I was just trying out.

I was able to populate a combobox with all of the states associated with a zip/city, but that's it.

```
// Connection string.
String cnStr;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

cnStr = "Data Source=000.00.000.00;Initial Catalog= ;User ID= ;Password= ";

// Assign Connection string to the connection object
cn.ConnectionString = cnStr;

// Open the connection to the SQL Server
cn.Open();

// This statement creates the command object and passes in the SQL statement
// then associates the command to the cn connection object
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct state, city from tblZipcodes order by state", cn);

// Open a DataReader
SqlDataReader rdrZip = cmd.ExecuteReader();

cn.Close();
```

The validation of a zipcode entered in a textbox and have the resulting state and city outputted to their respective labels, from SQL Server.

Comment: You will have to add a `where` clause to your sql query, and a `parameter` to your SqlCommand

Comment: I would I go about that?

Comment: You could use the TextBox `AutoCompleteSource` to trigger auto-completion of the ZIP code. That is, load all the details you need in a class, use the ZIP code field to fill the `TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource`. When a user selects a ZIPcode (from those that exist), you set other controls using the selected ZIPcode. The class that holds all the ZIP codes knows what are the corresponding elements (City, State etc.). This is all automatic and pre-validated. You also need to query the database just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use parameters, never ever build a sql query without parameters, because it leaves your application wide open for  `sql injection`.
You should use a where clause like this

```
var sql = "select distinct state, city from tblZipcodes where zipcode = @ZipCode";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = myZipCode.Text });

    SqlDataReader rdrZip = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` in case your columntype is `NVarChar` in stead of `VarChar`